# GraphQL schema stitching - Cannot read property 'args' of undefined

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

This is driving me nuts, simply because I can't get enough out of the error to trace it back. Google hasn't been much help either.

In a nutshell I've been trying to learn Schema Stitching using [this example](https://github.com/kriswep/graphql-microservices) and off the shelf it works fine. Then I tried swapping out the hardcoded data for my own "real" data (NoSQL collections stored in mLab) and I can query each API through the Gateway API just fine, but only seperately. The moment I try to stitch them I get `Cannot read property 'args' of undefined`. The minimal stack trace says its going wrong at `info.mergeInfo.delegateToSchema` in my fragment resolvers, but I can't even do a `console.log` which doesn't help.

I'm using **Mongoose** for my model/schema (which does work fine when I'm not trying to combine them, so I don't think its that).

My Post.user fragment:

```
export default schema => ({
  user: {
    fragment: `fragment PostFragment on Post { authorId }`,
    resolve(parent, args, context, info) {
      const id = parseInt(parent.user);
      return info.mergeInfo.delegateToSchema({
        schema,
        operation: 'query',
        fieldName: 'authorId',
        args: {
          id
        },
        context,
        info
      });
    }
  }
});
```

My main `post.js` resolver:

```
// ...
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    allPosts: async () => {
      const posts = await Post.find(); // works by itself

      return posts;
    },
    post: async (parent, { id }) => {
      const post = await Post.findById(id); // works by itself
      return post;
    }
  }
};

export default resolvers;
```

My relationsSchema:

```
const relationsSchema = `
  extend type User {
    posts: [Post]
  }

  extend type Post {
    author: User
  }
`;

export default relationsSchema;
```

And the schema merging:

```
import { mergeSchemas } from 'graphql-tools';

import makeResolvers from '../resolver';

import makePostSchema from '../remoteSchema/post';
import makeUserSchema from '../remoteSchema/user';
import relationsSchema from './relations';

// use schema stitching technique to merge schems together
export default async () => {
  const postSchema = await makePostSchema();
  const userSchema = await makeUserSchema();

  const resolvers = makeResolvers({ postSchema, userSchema });

  return mergeSchemas({
    schemas: [postSchema, userSchema, relationsSchema],
    resolvers
  });
};
```

I'll be happy to share some more code if you need it. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: By any chance, is your application using SSR?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same experience.
For me,

```
extend type User {
    Customer(id: string): [Orders]
}
```

This showed me args.id as whatever I passed id from the graphiql.